# Django. How to make html(tinymce) input safe on form.clean?

Tags: django, tinymce, strip-tags

For example, I have "Add comment" form on my django-powered website.
This form have `text` field with tinymce.

I want user to be able to use only `p,strong,i,ul,ol,li tags`. Because, result is html-code, I can't use `strip_tags` on my `AddCommentForm.clean_text` method. Also, I need to be sure, that result doesn't contain any vulnerabilities (js, iframe, etc)

I believe, that you can advice me a good solution for this))

Answer (score 0):

This can be done at the TinyMCE side via some configuration parameters. While it's not 100% secure fro someone POSTing directly, it's better than nothing.

It should just be a matter of tweaking your [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) config in your TinyMCE setup to only allow what you want:

```
 ...
 valid_elements : "p,strong/b,i/em,ul,ol,li",
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's good for client UI but totally insecure. I need some server-side solution.

Comment: Parse the html then - beautifulsoup may be your best chance/parser choice

Comment: stevejalim, do you have any examples or ideas how to use beautifulsoup for it?